# How to implement virtual IPs on AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, high-availability, virtual-ip

Is it possible to create floating IPs within Amazon? More specifically within the VPC? If so, how can I do this? Their documentation doesn't seem to point me in the right direction. The best I could find was this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ElasticNetworkInterfaces.html

> You can create an ENI, attach it to an instance, detach it from an
>   instance, and attach it to another instance. An ENI's attributes
>   follow the ENI as it is attached or detached from an instance and
>   reattached to another instance. When you move an ENI from one instance
>   to another, network traffic is redirected to the new instance.

But that can't be a *real* solution...

Comment: [ElasticIPs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#vpc-eips) might help you, but I am not even sure what floating IPs are...

Comment: I see... thanks for the pointer (I can't help you though, but check [ELB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/UserScenariosForVPC.html), it might be the way to go).

Comment: What are you trying to design for ? Mysql Fault tolerance/redundancy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this, it involves using the `ec2-associate-address` command line utility.

One would have to setup check scripts; and upon failure use `ec2-associate-address` to take over the elastic IP address. This only works with Elastic IPs (unfortunately) and is the closest I can get on AWS with virtual IPs.

More information is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html